# ASP.Net Identity not creating tables in MySQL DB

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am trying to get identity working with a MySQL DB. The problem is no tables are created hen I create a new user (register). When the form is submitted, an exception is thrown complaining that the table "`aspnetusers`" doesn't exist.

Here is my we.config file (sorry it's so long but I'm not 100% sure whats relevant and whats not)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
-->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ToolkitDB" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;password=test;database=testbedtoolkit" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

    <membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">      
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" 
             type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" 
             connectionStringName="ToolkitDB" 
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
             enablePasswordReset="true" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
             applicationName="/" 
             requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
             passwordFormat="Clear" 
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
             minRequiredPasswordLength="7" 
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" 
             passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
             passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
      </providers>      
    </membership>

    <profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLProfileProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" 
             type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" 
             connectionStringName="ToolkitDB" 
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLRoleProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLRoleProvider" 
             type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" 
             connectionStringName="ToolkitDB" 
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <siteMap defaultProvider="MySqlSiteMapProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" />
        <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" 
             type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" 
             connectionStringName="ToolkitDB" 
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>

    <webParts>
      <personalization defaultProvider="MySQLPersonalizationProvider">
        <providers>
          <remove name="MySQLPersonalizationProvider" />
          <add name="MySQLPersonalizationProvider" 
               type="MySql.Web.Personalization.MySqlPersonalizationProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" 
               connectionStringName="ToolkitDB" 
               applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
      </personalization>
    </webParts>

  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

And here is the `ApplicationDBContext` from `IdentityModel.cs`

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("ToolkitDB", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

So with the above, the app compiles and runs, it's just registering a new user that throws the exception. Let me know if I can provide more information. Thanks!

Comment: Check out the links below.  I think you might just need to add that autogenerateschema attribute to your config xml.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-asp-roles.html   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242644/using-mysql-mysqlmembershipprovider-autogenerateschema-true-not-working

Comment: @JoeIrby Didn't work... I put it in the web.config, as this is a testing machine. Is that OK? Or does it still need to go in machine.config? Thanks.

Comment: web.config said you use ***ASP.Net Membership***, but your code is using ***ASP.Net Identity***. They are two different things.